# Can a DLL be mapped into two process’ virtual address spaces at different virtual addresses?

Tags: memory, dll, process, virtual, memory-address

Can a DLL be mapped into two process’ virtual address spaces at different virtual addresses? If so, what problems arise? Can they be solved? If not, what can be done to eliminate them?

Comment: Yes.  It is very common.  We answer questions about problems *after* they occurred, no point in trying to make anything up.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes this is possible.

> [Win32 DLLs are mapped into the address space of the calling process. By default, each process using a DLL has its own instance of all the DLLs global and static variables.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h90dkhs0%28VS.80%29.aspx)